# which is more effective for seo purpose between facebook likebutton and facebook share

Tags: facebook

i want to add facebook share in my web site,
which one will be better for mainly seo purpose.
facebook like button or share.
is there any difference for SEO(search engine optimization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think share will be good for SEO... because share contribute more external links to the page, where as only the like count increases, which i dont think is the measure for google to rank the website.

Comment: Can you explain how share contributes more external links to the page when likes don't?  I thought both of them put up links, the like just requiring fewer clicks to do it and having no ability to add a custom message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what thobias said is correct, sharing helps to increase backlinks. But people hate to do more clicks if it is a like button the goal can be achieved in just a click. If it is share then they need to do 2 clicks which may slightly decrease your social media spread count.